# How to simplify a Ruby class before dumping to YAML?

Tags: ruby

I have a fragment of a YAML file written by hand:

```
:alerts:
  :ctlr_alerts:
    - :param: Collector temp
      :direction: '>'
      :value: 190
    - :param: 
      :direction: 
      :value: 
    - :param: 
      :direction: 
      :value:
```

This is read into a web server and the data is used to populate a form. If the user changes a value in the form, the new data is written back out to the YAML file, but it first gets uglified:

```
:alerts: 
  :ctlr_alerts: 
  - :param: !str:WEBrick::HTTPUtils::FormData 
      str: Collector temp
      "@filename": 
      "@header": &id001 {}

      "@name": alerts.ctlr_alerts.0.param
      "@next_data": 
      "@raw_header": &id002 []

    :value: !str:WEBrick::HTTPUtils::FormData 
      str: "190"
      "@filename": 
      "@header": *id001
```

etc...

I have some small utility scripts that run periodically that also read the same YAML file. Since adding the fragment above, they get the following error when trying to read in the file:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `transfer': invalid subclass (TypeError)
```

One workaround is to add

```
require 'webrick'
```

to each of the small scripts. But it seems ludicrous to have to suck in the code for the entire web server when the script has nothing to do with that. This is a small embedded system running ruby 1.8.6, and resources are a bit tight.

How can I "clean up" this data structure (cast it back to a simple array) before dumping it to YAML?

Comment: You're YAMLifying something that isn't a Hash, hence all the `!str:...` noise. So what code are you using to load the YAML, updated it, and then write it out again? There should be room for a `to_h` call (or similar) to get a plain Hash.

Comment: Thanks. I found something that works. Perhaps your suggestion is more elegant, but I'm not sure... the structure I'm having trouble with is supposed to be an array, not a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
if alert_change
  # convert from webrick form class to vanilla array
  alrts = @config[:alerts][:ctlr_alerts]
  aaa = []
  alrts.each do |a|
    aaa <<  { :param => a[:param].to_s,
      :direction => a[:direction].to_s,
      :value => a[:value].to_f}
  end
  @config[:alerts][:ctlr_alerts] = aaa
end

Predict.dump_config(@config)
@config = Predict.load_config
```

That worked!